# Как работает sort_values для нескольких столбцов в Pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame, который можно отсортировать при помощи `df.sort_values(by = 'Name')`, где Name - имя столбца по которому сортируем, однако как работает  `df.sort_values(by = ['Name', 'Name2'])` для двух или более столбцов?
Пример из оф. документации

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one': [2, 1, 1, 1],
                   'two': [1, 3, 2, 4],
                   'three': [5, 4, 3, 2]})
df1.sort_values(by=['one', 'two'])
```

Как мы получаем это?

```
   one  two  three
2    1    2     3
1    1    3     4
3    1    4     2
0    2    1     5
```

Comment: сортировка по второму столбцу "включается" тогда когда у вас одинаковые значения в первом столбце. В приведенном примере у вас есть две группы значений для первого столбца. Теперь каждую такую группу мы сортируем по второму столбцу, но только внутри этой группы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это работает точно так же, как в других подобных случаях, например, при `SQL` запросах к базе данных с сортировкой `ORDER BY` по нескольким столбцам. Сначала делается сортировка по первому столбцу, потом в тех строках, где значения первого столбца одинаковые - идёт сортировка по второму столбцу, потом в строках, где значения первого столбца совпадают и второго столбца тоже совпадают - идёт сортировка по третьему столбцу (если он указан) и т.д.

Answer (score 2):

В начале сортировка идет по первому значения `"one"`, те у которых `"one"` одинаковы сортировка идет по`"two"` и так далее.